# Kubernetes dashboard (web UI) not working

Tags: kubernetes

I have just started a new Kubernetes 1.8.0 environment using minikube (0.27) on Windows 10.

I followed this steps but it didn't work:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/web-ui-dashboard/

When I list pods this is the result:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>kubectl get pods --all-namespaces    
NAMESPACE     NAME                                    READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   etcd-minikube                           1/1       Running            0          23m    
kube-system   heapster-69b5d4974d-s9vrf               1/1       Running            0          5m    
kube-system   kube-addon-manager-minikube             1/1       Running            0          23m    
kube-system   kube-apiserver-minikube                 1/1       Running            0          23m    
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-minikube        1/1       Running            0          23m    
kube-system   kube-dns-545bc4bfd4-xkt7l               3/3       Running            3          1h    
kube-system   kube-proxy-7jnk6                        1/1       Running            0          23m    
kube-system   kube-scheduler-minikube                 1/1       Running            0          23m    
kube-system   kubernetes-dashboard-5569448c6d-8zqnc   1/1       Running            2          52m    
kube-system   kubernetes-dashboard-869db7f6b4-ddlmq   0/1       CrashLoopBackOff   19         51m    
kube-system   monitoring-influxdb-78d4c6f5b6-b66m9    1/1       Running            0          4m    
kube-system   storage-provisioner                     1/1       Running            2          1h
```

As you can see, I have 2 kubernets-dashboard pods now, one of then is running and the other one is CrashLookBackOff.

When I try to run minikube dashboard this is the result:

> "Waiting, endpoint for service is not ready yet..."

I have tried to remove kubernetes-dashboard-869db7f6b4-ddlmq pod:

```
kubectl delete pod kubernetes-dashboard-869db7f6b4-ddlmq
```

This is the result:

> "Error from server (NotFound): pods "kubernetes-dashboard-869db7f6b4-ddlmq" not found"

Answer (score 1):

> "Error from server (NotFound): pods "kubernetes-dashboard-869db7f6b4-ddlmq" not found"

You failed to delete the pod due to the lack of namespace (add `-n kube-system`). And it should be 1 dashboard pod if no modification's applied. If it still fails to run minikube dashboard after you delete the abnormal pod, more logs should be provided.